# Java memory profiling in AWS Lambda

Tags: java, aws-lambda, heap-memory, memory-profiling

Is it possible to profile memory usage of java projects in AWS Lambda with classes or packages of all objects on the heap?

**Heap memory profiling**:
[image: heap memory profiling]

Answer (score 2):

Since August 2017, AWS has provided SAM local which allows lambda functions to be run locally.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/sam-cli-requirements.html

> The AWS SAM CLI is a command line tool that operates on an AWS SAM template and application code. With the AWS SAM CLI, you can invoke Lambda functions locally, create a deployment package for your serverless application, deploy your serverless application to the AWS Cloud, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You need [docker](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda) - to start your lambda locally. If you are in admin / docker group you can connect to the process with your profiler.